# Long click to display the content of another activity in the same activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to imitate Instagram on long click feature in my application. 
I have a list view and when the user clicks an item, it opens a details activity.

what i'm trying to do is to display the details to the user when long pressing an item *without moving to the details activity, i need to display it in the center of the screen in the same activity* (like when you long press on a picture in Instagram) and disappears when the user release the touch.

I have tired the following:

```
 view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        Log.d("LongClick", "Long click");
                        Intent in = new Intent(AppointmentsActivity.this,AppointmentsDetailsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(in);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                            Log.d("TouchTest", "Touch down");
                        } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                            Log.d("TouchTest", "Touch up");

                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, just open another activity onLongPress as dialog activity.So Content of detail activity will show in current activity.
To open the activity as dialog activity, you need to set activity theme as dialog theme 
< activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />

Answer (score 0):

For These you don't need to start new Activity. you have only to have  datas (preferences or a class with variable).  Then  with a simple dialogbox you can do that or with a fragment. Because you can't run 2 Activities in the mean time. And if you want to start detail Activity for resons of memorie, your launch activity may be killed and don't still in backstack.

Comment: how can i achieve that with the fragment?

Answer (score 0):

as  user2043602 said, you don't need to start a new activity.,

According to me the best alternative is to use **ViewAnimator** with two layouts,
and dynamically add a fragment to the second layout[which is not visible, until you move to next view in ViewAnimator].

to add fragment at run-time, you can use the following:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction;
transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
page_1 newFragment1 = page_1.newInstance("one", "two");//here page_1 is my fragment..which you can easily do by adding a new default blank fragment in android studio
transaction.add(R.id.holder, newFragment1);//R.id.holder is the layout id under whihc you wish to add the fragment..
```

you can you ViewAnimator like this:

```
ViewAnimator viewAnimator;
viewAnimator = (ViewAnimator)findViewById(R.id.group1);//R.id.group1 is the view animator id
viewAnimator.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(page2.this, R.anim.first_try));         viewAnimator.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(page2.this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right));

            viewAnimator.showNext();
```